# Configuring BOX OAuth app for iOS & Desktop

Tags: oauth-2.0, box-api, box, boxapiv2

I am trying to configure OAuth app flow for BOX app in  both Desktop and iOS platforms. But in BOX app console, it is allowing to give one redirect URI either iOS or desktop. How can i configure it to work for both.

I want to give redirect uri  :

For iOS : boxsdk-clientId://boxsdkoauth2redirect
For Desktop : http://localhost:6900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge Box does not allow you to specify multiple redirect URIs for an application. You will need to create a separate application for each redirect URI, e.g. "My App for iOS" and "My App for Desktop".